# Several Ids in input in CSS

Tags: html, css

So I want to customize several inputs. I tried with this and it works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

input[id=a]:focus {
  width: 250px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The width Property</h1>

Searcha: <input type="text" name="search" id="a">
Searchb: <input type="text" name="search" id="b">

</body>
</html>
```

However, I wanted to put more ids on input. It´s possible?

```
//try
    input[id=a b]:focus {
      width: 250px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a selector that can target multiple values of a single attribute.

Instead you'll unfortunately need a comma separated list of the whole selector with different values like so:

```
input[id="a"]:focus, input[id="b"]:focus {
  width: 250px;
}
```

A class in this case would be more beneficial.

Answer (score 4):

You can chain selectors in css like this:

```
#foo, #bar {
    color: red
}
```

However, if you have >5 ids this can get a bit tedious and at that point it would be better to use a class:

HTML:

```
<input class="search-input" />
<input class="search-input" />
```

CSS:

```
.search-input {
    color: red
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I already have class for these inputs. Did not put on example because my goal were to set to ids.

Comment: @Goldbones you can have multiple classes - but not multiple ids. However, in CSS specificity is a thing, and IDs win the battle against classes in what styles to apply. But you can get around by being more specific with your class (e.g. `parent-container input.search-input` will beat IDs most of the time)

Answer (score 2):

`#a, #b {}`

It's really that simple.